# Parse two integers in a string and assign them to two bash variables?

Tags: bash

I have a program that returns two non-negative integers, as a string separated by a space. I need to run this program inside a bash script, and I need to assign the output integers to two variables `$i` and `$j`.

For definiteness, suppose I ran the program inside the script and stored its output in a variable `$out`, so that `$out` contains a string such as `56 2`. Now I need to parse `$out` somehow to end with the integers assigned to `i` and `j` respectively.
How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want an intermediate variable do `read i j < <(yourProgram)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell +1 Thanks, that works. Can you explain the `< <`'s and why `<<<` doesn't work?

Comment: `<(program)` is called `bash process substitution` and basically it takes the output of a program and makes it look like a file, then the other `<` makes the `read` statement take that "file" as input. The `<<<` operator passes a following string as `stdin` to a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign the values in `out` to the variables `i` and `j`, all you need is a `read` statement:

```
$ out="56 2"
$ read i j <<<"$out"
$ echo i=$i j=$j
i=56 j=2
```

The `<<<` signifies that the `read` statement should take its stdin from the Here string specified by the variable `out`.

#### Reading two variables directly from a command

For specificity, let's suppose that the command is `date` and we want to read the hour and minute:

```
$ date +'%H %M'
15 45
```

To get those into variables, use:

```
$ read i j < <(date +'%H %M')
$ echo i=$i j=$j
i=15 j=45
```

The syntax above is a bit tricky.  The construct `<(...)` makes the output of a program into a file-like object.  (This is called "process substitution.")  In this case the program is `date +'%H %M'`.  In order to tell `read` to read its input (stdin) from that file-like object, we use redirection, signified by `<`.  Thus `< <(...)` says to take stdin from the output of the command in parens.

The space between `<` and `<(...)` is essential.  That is because `<<` means something else entirely: it indicates the start of a Here document.    So, keep the space.

Comment: +1 That works. Now I'm trying to skip the temp variable `out`, and use the output of the program directly in the `read` statement, but it doesn't work. Note that the program takes several arguments, so I was trying something like `read i j <<<(prog arg1 arg2))`, but it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: See Mark Setchell's comment to your question.

Comment: @becko I updated the answer with an approach that removes the intermediate variable as well as an explanation of why the space is important.

Answer (score -1):

A solution I could propose you is to use the *cut* program within Linux. This tool is included in every distribution. Basically it would look like this:

```
$out = program
$i = echo $out | cut -d" " -f1
$j = echo $out | cut -d" " -f2
```

The parameter -d" " specifies to divide your string using the space character, the -fX specify to return the X column. So for example,

```
$out = "56 2"
echo "56 2" | cut -d" " -f1
>56
```

Comment: `$i = echo $out | cut -d" " -f1` is no valid bash code.